# How to read Values from a web page using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am very very new to python but I have started an internship that requires me to do some python work, I am asked to create an application that can retrieve data from a webpage(IP address) and then compare those values to the correct values and then print out if it has passed or not. Please check this diagram I have made so that you guys can understand it better. Please take a look.
[image: Steps needed to execute this application]

So far I have only written some python code to check if the website/ip address is up or not but I have no idea how to go further. could you guys please help me to execute the further steps with some examples maybe?

Here is a picture of the website. the values circled in red color need to be compared with the Auxiliary Values I hope this picture helps.
[image]

However, I could use  http://192.168.100.2/globals.xml on this page to compare the values. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import eventlet
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

eventlet.monkey_patch()
with eventlet.Timeout(10):
    print(urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5").getcode())
    print("Website is UP") 
    
eventlet.monkey_patch()
with eventlet.Timeout(10):
    print(urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2").getcode())
    print("Website is UP")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are off to a great start! Your next steps should be identifying unique traits about the elements that you want to scrape. Specifically, look for things like class or id names that are unique to only the data that you want to scrape.

You can also use tools like Selector Gadget (https://selectorgadget.com/) that can help automate the process. Unfortunately, since you are accessing local IP addresses, nobody here will be able to help you find these.

After you find the proper selectors, you can use BeautifulSoup to view the data. I'd recommend looking at the `find` and `findall` commands that BeautifulSoup has.